# Python3 - Get most central rectangle from list of coordinates

Tags: python

I have an array of rectangle coordinates in `python3` that looks like this...

```
shapes[[(61, 52) (124, 106)],
       [(43, 328) (233, 472)],
       [(259, 230) (328, 305)]
       [(354, 114) (452, 218)]
]
```

[image]

I know the width of the area that these shapes sit on is 500x500, I am trying to find out which of the shapes is the most central on both horizontal and vertical directions and then create a new array with the result like this...

```
shapes[[(259, 230) (328, 305)]]
```

Anyone have any examples of something similar being solved? Is this purely a maths based solution or is there something specific in Python to do the calculation more effectively?

Comment: Define "most central"? How would you combine the "centralness" metric along both axes in order to compare candidate rectangles?

Comment: generally, problems this specific don't have "ready made" solutions out there. Also, this looks like a simple enough problem to build a solution for.

Comment: I was thinking that trying to find the coordinate closest to 250,250 is probably the simplest way of doing it. Just wanted to see if anybody else had a more efficient approach

Comment: Why not just compute the absolute differences between coordinates of the vertexes and the coordinates of the center of your zone?

Comment: Or maybe the distance between the center of each rectangle to the 250,250 point?

Comment: That seems like a good alternative, will build something now and try it out. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that the most central rectangle is the one that its centre is closest to the centre of surrounding square (250, 250). Using `min` with the distance from  the centre as the key function shall return the wanted result

```
shapes = [
    [(61, 52), (124, 106)],
    [(43, 328), (233, 472)],
    [(259, 230), (328, 305)],
    [(354, 114), (452, 218)],
]


def centre(r):
    """
    return centre of rectangle
    """
    return (r[0][0] + r[1][0]) / 2, (r[0][1] + r[1][1]) / 2


def sqr_dist(a, b):
    """
    return square of distance between points a and b
    """
    return (a[0] - b[0]) ** 2 + (a[1] - b[1]) ** 2


square_centre = (250, 250)
most_central = min(shapes, key=lambda r: sqr_dist(centre(r), square_centre))
```

Result:

```
>>> most_central
[(259, 230), (328, 305)]
```